# Apache Tomcat server with SSL, how to not showing port when open site

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

When I open my site [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) Tomcat redirect and show [www.example.com:8443](http://www.example.com:8443).
I want when someone open site not to show port 8443. How to solve that problem?

I use tomcat 9.0.68. I installed application on tomcat and set to use SSL on port 8443.
server.xml now look like this:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />


<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
  <SSLHostConfig>
    <Certificate certificateFile="conf/cert.pem"
                 certificateKeyFile="conf/privkey.pem"
                 certificateChainFile="conf/chain.pem" />
  </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

And in web.xml I added:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPSOnly</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

What I need to configure more to open site without showing port 8443?

Comment: Make it listen on port 443.

Comment: That's how I resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.

The best way, in my opinion, is using authbind: https://serverfault.com/questions/889122/how-to-get-tomcat-9-to-work-with-authbind-to-bind-to-port-80

It's my opinion this is the best way as the port is allocated directly to the process and follows the unix convention of doing things.

There are other options:

- Use haproxy to splice the TCP connections
- Use iptables to redirect the port
- Use Apache/nginx to proxy the request